# How can I preserve a new object hierarchy in an ActiveRecord conditional update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a small AR object hierarchy, say a `Parent` which `has_many` `Child` objects, instantiating and associating each as I go.

Now that I have that, I need to check whether the `Parent` already exists before saving, and if it does then update the entire hierarchy with potentially new values for each attribute of every object.

I can't `find_or_create` first. I have to build the hierarchy and then do the check and create or update.

How does Rails handle that? If I only had the parent it would be much simpler, but all the attached objects make it more difficult.

Comment: Paste your code..what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can manage this through nested form and it is useful to store the parent/child relation data.

Hope it is helpful for you!!